# NOTICE: One or more columns in the following table(s) do not have statistics error in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, greenplum

I am running a PostgreSQL query through a shell script.

Below is the query used in the script:

query 1:

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns
where data_type like '%timestamp%'
  and table_name not like '%_1_prt_%';
```

query2:

```
select max(date_column)
from table_schema.table_name;
```

but while running the script I am getting this error:

```
NOTICE:  One or more columns in the following table(s) do not have statistics: ops_support
HINT:  For non-partitioned tables, run analyze <table_name>(<column_list>). For partitioned tables, run analyze rootpartition <table_name>(<column_list>).
See log for columns missing statistics
```

Could you please help me to resolve the error or why I am getting the below error??

Comment: Where is the error? `NOTICE` is an informational message, not a error... Also the `HINT` says perform a `ANALYZE` command on the table...

Comment: be sure to not include postgresql in your tags if you are using greenplum.

Answer (score 1):

fixed for me:

```
ANALYZE table_schema.table_name;
```